# Can I use my router to redirect outgoing traffic from one domain to another?

Tags: networking, router

So for instance, how can I make it so that if someone types "somewhere.com" into their browser, it will go to `192.168.xxx.xxx` instead? I have a [Portal](https://portalwifi.com) router (Version: V1.0, Firmware: Portal-1.4.240_prod-1.2.226 ), but I'm not opposed to setting something like pfSense up.

I'm doing this so that my girlfriend doesn't have to type an IP address into her browser to access a web thing I made for her.

Comment: please edit subject "to another": an ip address is not a domain

Comment: This is what DNS was invented for

Comment: @Mark so how do I use DNS to do this?

Comment: @Mark "from one domain to another" is not what DNS does - domain names are resolved to IP addresses

Comment: @Displayname please also specify how client and server should connect to each other before talking about DNS implementation: LAN, VPN or port forwarding?

Comment: @Furty, although the title of the question suggests Display name wants to arrange a redirect, I hope we can agree the question itself: "if someone types 'somewhere.com' into their browser, it will go to 192.168.xxx.xxx" suggests s/he is more interested in resolving a name to an IP address

Comment: @Displayname what OS are you (/your gf) using? I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the Portal routers - do you know what model of hardware your router is?

Answer (score -1):

a) for a VPN connection to your 192.168.xxx.xxx web thing:
buy a domain or simply let her use a browser bookmark

b) if the girlfriend computer is on the LAN:
[change her hosts file](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/)
or setup your own DNS server